# What is the maximum number of countries that can leave the XCOM project at the end of the month?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

And does it change based on the difficulty level?  In my last game on Normal difficulty, I had six countries at maximum panic (5/5) at the end of the month, but only two decided to leave the project.  Is that a fixed number?  Would all six countries have left if I was playing on Classic or Impossible difficulty?

Comment: @Chris - Sorry, I meant maximum panic.  All six countries had 5 bars filled in.

Comment: I may have been wrong but the clarification is worth it anyway. I'll delete my comment now since its no longer relevant. :)

Comment: From what I understand, when you have multiple countries at max panic, each one has a *chance* to leave the council.

Comment: Unless I'm misremembering, I had a four or five countries leave at once, with several, but not all of them at maximum panic, on impossible difficulty. I understood it as one of the leaving max-panic countries convincing a few others non-maxed countries to go with it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the [ini files](http://wiki.tesnexus.com/index.php/XCOM:EU_DefaultGameCore.ini_settings), there are the following settings:

```
PANIC_DEFECTIONS_PER_MONTH_EASY=1
PANIC_DEFECTIONS_PER_MONTH_NORMAL=2 
PANIC_DEFECTIONS_PER_MONTH_HARD=3 
PANIC_DEFECTIONS_PER_MONTH_CLASSIC=8
```

Comment: Does this mean "HARD" is Classic difficulty and "CLASSIC" is Impossible difficulty?

Comment: @StrixVaria Yes.

Comment: So yes, if you manage to screw up absolutely spectacularly, you can lose the game by defections in a single month.

Comment: ... Of course, you can lose much easier and much quicker by simply getting your entire team killed during the first mission if you skip the tutorial...

Comment: From that site, there is also a set of PANIC_DEFECT_CHANCE_PER_BLOCK entries, so it appears that @SaintWacko is also correct - there is a % chance of each country leaving the project, but the maximum number is capped based on difficulty level you are playing at.

Comment: that's kind of silly, so if you edit your ini files you can cap it to 0 and ignore panic completely?

Comment: @spartacus - That's modding for you.  Though according to various XCOM modding threads, there is a bit more involved, as the INI file is stored within the EXE as a resource, so you have to get it out, modify the value and then put it back.

Comment: @spartacus in addition to what Jason said about extracting the ini file, we have no idea what the code looks like that consumes this value.  That code may interpret 0 as unlimitted.