# Can local nations leave the council due to panic?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I'm playing Classic Ironman difficulty on my iPhone. My XCOM base is in Germany.  Russia's panic reached 5 and I was unable to deploy a satellite before the Council Report came in. I was then shocked to see that Russia did not leave the XCOM program. This has left me with two possible theories:

1. Local nations are "in it to win it" and will not secede despite maximum panic levels.
2. There is some (small) chance that nations with maximum panic will not secede when the council gives their report.

I am forced to assume that local nations will still immediately secede if a terror mission is ignored (not too keen on testing that out). And perhaps neither of the above theories are correct.

Has anyone else witnessed a nation with 5 panic staying with the program? If local nations will not secede, it would seem it is safe to ignore them until all other satellites are placed... but that seems too easy. But that's my question: **Is it possible for local nations to secede from the XCOM project during council reports?**

Comment: According to the [INI files](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/98383/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-countries-that-can-leave-the-xcom-project-at-the-e#comment134359_98393), there is a percentage chance for each country to leave when at 5 bars.  However, the only time I have ever seen a country not leave is when I've maxed out the number of countries that can leave for a specific difficulty level.

Comment: Is the iOS version identical to the PC version? Did you lose *any* countries that month?

Comment: @RavenDreamer I did not lose any countries that month. I deployed 3 satellites to other countries that each had 5 panic and let Russia go because I already had the continent bonus. So far as I know, the iOS version is nearly a direct port, though of course the interface had to be modified to support touch interactions, graphics were toned down, and some maps were removed.

Comment: Then it seems likely that there is some small chance nations at 5 panic won't leave (as I've also witnessed this, once, in the PC version). Either way, I don't believe "local nation" is not a concept the game abides by.

Comment: @JasonBerkan That link was broken but I found the latest: [XCOM INI File](http://wiki.tesnexus.com/index.php/DefaultGameCore.ini_settings_-_XCOM:EU_2012).  LOTS of interesting info there...

Comment: This may be because (I think), a country that has risen to panic level 5 will not leave within 14 days of rising to that level. I read that somewhere on a wiki, and so far in my experience it seems to be true sometimes and not others. Maybe the shorter they are at maximum panic, the less chance they have of leaving?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nations leaving is a percentage chance. There is a maximum number of countries that can leave each month (based on difficulty) as well as a percentage chance to leave at 5 panic. Having satellites in the country (and neighboring countries) reduces the chance of the country leaving the XCOM project.

To answer the title question: **Yes**, it is possible for local nations to leave due to panic. However you have inherent bonuses from nearby satellites that reduce the chances of this happening.

Source: INI file and analysis mentioned here: http://www.reddit.com/r/Xcom/comments/1aadl8/probabilities_of_nation_leaving_the_council_at_5/

Answer (score 4):

It absolutely is possible for nations in your continent to secede.

My guess is that this was caused because 3 other nations left at the same time, since only 3 can leave per month on classic difficulty.

Comment: No other nations left.

Comment: @bpcookson Well, I haven't played the iphone port, so that may be the issue. Whether it is a bug or intentional change I don't know. But I have never had a country not leave except when hitting the cap